# What's the purpose of default users inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Recently we were asked to remove unnecessary users from our images to comply with the PCI DSS requirement 2.1:

> 2.1 Always change vendor-supplied defaults and remove or disable unnecessary default accounts before installing a system on the network.

The rationale behind this requirement is to not multuply entities beyond necessity and reduce the number of possible attack vectors. On the one hand what the accessor asked us to do makes perfect sense. On the other hand containers already run in a constrained namespaced environment.

Let's describe it with a few examples.
The first one is the dumbest - run as root, no security enforced, etc.

```
$ docker run --rm -ti alpine
/ # cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:13:news:/usr/lib/news:/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:14:uucp:/var/spool/uucppublic:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/bin/sh
man:x:13:15:man:/usr/man:/sbin/nologin
postmaster:x:14:12:postmaster:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
cron:x:16:16:cron:/var/spool/cron:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:21:21::/var/lib/ftp:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:22:22:sshd:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
at:x:25:25:at:/var/spool/cron/atjobs:/sbin/nologin
squid:x:31:31:Squid:/var/cache/squid:/sbin/nologin
xfs:x:33:33:X Font Server:/etc/X11/fs:/sbin/nologin
games:x:35:35:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
postgres:x:70:70::/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/sh
cyrus:x:85:12::/usr/cyrus:/sbin/nologin
vpopmail:x:89:89::/var/vpopmail:/sbin/nologin
ntp:x:123:123:NTP:/var/empty:/sbin/nologin
smmsp:x:209:209:smmsp:/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
guest:x:405:100:guest:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
/ # su -s /bin/sh nobody
~ $ whoami
nobody
~ $ su
su: must be suid to work properly
```

This example shows that we can easily switch from root to a regular user inside the container meaning that anyone who could break into the host could jump into container as root and switch to the user the main container's process is running on behalf of. Apparently you can't `su` running as a regular user. And of course you are free to `setcap` in order to give more freedom to non-priviliged users.

```
$ docker run --rm -ti alpine                                                
/ # apk add libcap; setcap cap_net_raw=+ep /bin/busybox
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing libcap (2.25-r1)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
OK: 4 MiB in 14 packages
/ # getcap /bin/busybox
/bin/busybox = cap_net_raw+ep
```

But let's add some more flags (which are sane defaults for all of our containers in fact):

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --cap-drop all --security-opt no-new-privileges alpine
/ # su -s /bin/sh nobody
su: can't set groups: Operation not permitted
/ # apk add libcap
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing libcap (2.25-r1)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
ERROR: busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger: script exited with error 127
OK: 4 MiB in 14 packages
/ # setcap cap_net_raw=+ep /bin/busybox
unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effective capability: Operation not permitted
```

Let's now do this kind of thing. Can we run a container from the arbitrary user, as someone who is not present in `/etc/passwd`:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --cap-drop all --security-opt no-new-privileges --user 60000:60000 alpine
/ $ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 60000
/ $ id
uid=60000 gid=60000
```

Ok, this means that effectively we can run a container with any `uid:gid` pair no matter if it is present inside a container actually or not.

Now what will happen if we completely remove the information about users from the container:

```
$ docker build -f- .<<EOF
FROM alpine
RUN rm -f /etc/shadow /etc/group /etc/passwd
EOF
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.607kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 196d12cf6ab1
Step 2/2 : RUN rm -f /etc/shadow /etc/group /etc/passwd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7c22df16e0dd
Successfully built 7c22df16e0dd

$ docker run --rm -ti --user 60000:60000 7c22df16e0dd 
/ $ touch /etc/passwd /etc/group
touch: /etc/passwd: Permission denied
touch: /etc/group: Permission denied
/ $ adduser lol
adduser: permission denied (are you root?)
/ $ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 60000
/ $ id
uid=60000 gid=60000
```

And yet if `--user 60000:60000` is removed we will identify ourselves as an effective root:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti 7c22df16e0dd 
/ # touch /etc/passwd /etc/group
/ # adduser lol
passwd: unknown uid 0
/ # cat /etc/passwd
lol:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/lol:/bin/sh
/ # su lol
/ $ whoami
lol
```

Now let's check if there is anything that can be relevant to users present in default `passwd` and `group` files. Apparently there is no processes. But as for files:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti alpine:3.8
/ # for user in `cat /etc/passwd | grep -v -E ^root | cut -d ':' -f 1`; do find / -xdev -user $user;done
/ # 

$ docker run --rm -ti debian:9  
root@4fac719bb234:/# for user in `cat /etc/passwd | grep -v -E ^root | cut -d ':' -f 1`; do find / -xdev -user $user;done
root@4fac719bb234:/# 

$ docker run --rm -ti centos:7
[root@fa1242222f1e /]# for user in `cat /etc/passwd | grep -v -E ^root | cut -d ':' -f 1`; do echo "=== $user ==="; find / -xdev -user $user;done
=== bin ===
=== daemon ===
=== adm ===
=== lp ===
=== sync ===
=== shutdown ===
=== halt ===
=== mail ===
=== operator ===
=== games ===
=== ftp ===
=== nobody ===
=== systemd-network ===
/run/systemd/netif
/run/systemd/netif/leases
/run/systemd/netif/links
=== dbus ===
```

CentOS container is the only one who has got files owned by a non-root user.

Some thoughts and observations:

1. Running a container with `--read-only --cap-drop all --security-opt no-new-privileges` and `--user` with `uid:gid` higher than 0 seems enough to protect it from gaining additional privileges.
2. The `uid:gid` pair can be any pair of numbers.
3. [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html) lists only `root` as a required user with `bin` and `daemon` marked as legacy and a bunch of optional users none of which make any sense in case of base container images.

The questions are:

1. Why all those users (especially thoise beyond listed in [LSB](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html)) exist in base images and what risk do they add?
2. Can we remove all but `root` and leave creating additional users as an excercise to application developers/package creators/et al.?
3. Does it make sense to remove the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` entirely bearing in mind that containers run as `root` implicitly by default no matter if these files are present in the system or not and we are still able to use any `uid:gid` pair where `uid` > 0 and `gid` > 0 which will effectively mean running as non-root?

Comment: do you know about namespaces and how they work , please read the user namespace and read how to use that and dont try to mount the host uid namespace to container

Comment: So...if you’re asking this question at all...being able to `docker` anything implies root access on the host (you can trivially add yourself to the host’s `/etc/sudoers` as a minimal example).  The examples that start with “someone who has root on the host, can get root in a container, and then can...” seem a little contrived.

Comment: @IjazKhan user namespaces are out of scope of this question. Consider the above examples run with the remapped user namespace.

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree that the example with "someone who has root on host" is contrived. Since if you find yourself in this situation you're pwned anyway... =)

Comment: So far as I know, the simplest image built from `scratch` does not include `/etc` files. Maybe you could build your own OS image to meet special requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement makes little sense to me in the context of containers. The users listed in the /etc/passwd file are a mapping of uid to username. They do not have any login credentials, that's controlled by /etc/shadow. And there is no login or similar daemon running inside the container unless you explicitly start one yourself. Having the uid to name mapping gives the advantage that directory listing commands will show a user name instead of a uid. It also assists with application install scripts that run commands as different users by username for security.

As an aside, if you want security I would recommend having a user defined inside the container to run your application, assuming your application can be run by a non-root user. While root inside the container has fewer capabilities than a normal root user (to prevent the ability to escape the container), a non-root user is even further constrained. And whatever user you run commands as inside the container should be defined in your /etc/passwd file. That said, even if your application is running as root inside the container, that user is so limited with reduced capabilities and isolated to a namespace that has little ability to do damage. The risks are, to the best of my knowledge, theoretical, or require additional security holes to exploit. Running applications as a non-root user is therefore an added layer of security should a future exploit be discovered.

Overall, this feels like a requirement created by someone skilled in locking down Linux servers and VM's, but failing to understand why a policy that makes sense on a multi-user host does not make sense in a container environment. I would challenge them to show what exploits are made possible by /etc/passwd entries that doesn't also involve treating a container like a VM with things like adding /etc/shadow entries and an sshd daemon.

---

To answer the specific questions:

> 1. Why all those users (especially thoise beyond listed in LSB) exist in base images and what risk do they add?

These come from a tar file of a minimal OS filesystem for the base image distribution. I suspect they are assumed to exist and are there for package installers that depend on these users. There's no real value add to removing them, but a real risk to breaking installers.

> 2. Can we remove all but root and leave creating additional users as an excercise to application developers/package creators/et al.?

Could you? Yes. But to me this is an example of security introducing potential failures into an existing system without adding value. I have seen some applications break when the uid does not exist in the /etc/passwd file, so I don't recommend running commands as an unlisted uid without lots of testing.

> 3. Does it make sense to remove the /etc/passwd and /etc/group entirely bearing in mind that containers run as root implicitly by default no matter if these files are present in the system or not and we are still able to use any uid:gid pair where uid > 0 and gid > 0 which will effectively mean running as non-root?

I'm fairly certain this will cause things to break. You can try this in your environment, but would be in an unsupported configuration. Note that there may be some binaries installed in the filesystem with suid/sgid functionality configured and giving users access to these uid/gid's could introduce security vulnerabilities that would be solved by maintaining a mapping of the currently used uid/gid's and running your application as a new uid/gid. The built in functionality to do this is, you guessed it, /etc/passwd.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. As an experiment we are running a couple of containers with `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` removed and everything has been ok so far. Why do you think it will be an unsupported configuration? why any non-root user should be defined in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`?As for binaries with suid/sgid functionality and sensitive to presense of valid  `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` it is better that you are aware of those packages and have control over them or over packaging them.